# How do injected classes get a reference to the injector?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I recently started using Dagger 2 in a small Android project.  I'm not sure I understand where I should build my `@Component`.

Say I have a `@Module` providing dependencies that in turn depend on the `Application`.  Obviously, you cannot instantiate the `@Module`, and therefore cannot build the `@Component`, without a reference to the `Application`.  In that case, does it make sense for the `Application` itself to build and hold a reference to the `@Component`, which activities and fragments can then obtain to inject themselves?  In other words, instead of this:

```
MyComponent component = DaggerMyComponent.builder()
    .myModule(new MyModule((MyApp) getApplication()))
    .build();
component.inject(this);
```

Activities would just do this:

```
((MyApp) getApplication()).getMyComponent().inject(this);
```

Are there any drawbacks to doing it the second way?  And if the module provides `@Singleton` dependencies, is it *necessary* to do it the second way?

**Edit:** I wrote a non-Android test program.  As I would expect, different instances of the `@Component` interface produce different instances of `@Singleton` resources.  So it appears that the answer to my last question is yes, unless there's some other mechanism for the `@Component` itself being a singleton.

```
final AppComponent component1 = DaggerAppComponent.create();
final AppComponent component2 = DaggerAppComponent.create();
System.out.println("same AppComponent: " + component1.equals(component2)); // false
// the Bar producer is annotated @Singleton
System.out.println("same component, same Bar: " + component1.bar().equals(component1.bar())); // true
System.out.println("different component, same Bar: " + component1.bar().equals(component2.bar())); // false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion is correct. A `@Singleton` component only guarantees one instance of `@Singleton`-scoped things for its lifetime, so your application has to hold onto that component.

Comment: I found a [tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2) that backs this up: "We should do all this work within an `Application` class since these instances should be declared only once throughout the entire lifespan of the application."

Answer (score 1):

Your component has to be in an interface. Lets say you have a module as such

```
@Module
public class MainActivityModule {

    @Provides
    public Gson getGson(){
        return new Gson();
    }
}
```

Now you want to make an interface for this module so you can use it in your activity. I inject the activity into this interface, but this will be tricky when you want to use for many other activities so for now lets just say you want to use the MainActivity

```
@Component(
    modules = MainActivityModule.class) //The module you created 
public interface IAppModule {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

Now you can use in your MainActivity but first build the project because Dagger2 needs to make its own classes dependent on the module and component you have made. Note that you have not made the class `DaggerIAppModule` it has been created after you have built the project

```
IAppModule appComponent;

@Inject
Gson gson;

public void setupDaggerGraph(){ //call this method in your onCreate()
    appComponent = DaggerIAppModule.builder()
            .mainActivityModule(new MainActivityModule())
            .build();
    appComponent.inject(this);
}
```

Comment: The `@Module` in your example doesn't depend on the `Application`.

Comment: It is used in `@Component` in the interface IAppModule? Im not too sure what you mean...

Comment: As for your edited post, you cannot inject any activity to the same component you have to create a component for each activity, and if your using the same module for each one you can just use it as a dependency so the same singleton will be used. @KevinKrumwiede

Comment: Instead of `new MyModule()`, it's `new MyModule(getApplication())`.  That being the case, I'm asking whether it makes sense to have the application instantiate `MyModule` and provide a getter for the interface.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "you have to create a component for each activity."  I haven't tried it with activities, but my test app uses the same component instance to inject all of its fragments, i.e., `((MyApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getMyComponent().inject(this);`